# How to customize <head></head>

Tags: customization, pages, wp-head

I want to customize `<head>` tags, add my own structured data snippet, instead of generated by Yoast. And how to gain overall control of `<head>` tags contents over pages. How this will be done without and with SEO plugin.

Comment: Hello, @dimmed - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Please note that questions regarding 3rd-party plugins are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) within our community. The best place to receive support for such items is the 3rd-party's official support channels. Please review the [ask] section of our [help] to learn more about what questions are a good fit here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add your own tags to WordPress pages use the [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action.

To modify or remove `<head>` elements being added by Yoast you'll need to use the [filters they provide](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/#filters). As documented in that link you can modify the page title, author, keywords and more.